# always_ff or always_comb for clock generation in a simple TestBench

Tags: system-verilog

Which one is to be used with clock generation for a simple testbench? 
For eg:

```
always #20 clk <= ~clk
```

if I change it to either always_ff or always_comb both gives error

```
Statements in an always_comb shall not include those that block, have 
  blocking timing or event controls, or forkjoin statements. The always_ff 
  procedure imposes the restriction that it contains one and only one event 
  control and no blocking timing controls.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. Stick to the ordinary `always`.  `always_comb` and `always_ff` are for your design.